# Why is it "Google Maps", not "Google Map"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In my native language, "map" is usually singular, unless you have a map drawn on lots of separate pieces of paper. So online services in my country that are similar to Google Maps usually contain "Map" (in singular form) in their names.

If you think about Google Maps, it just offers one huge map covering the whole planet. How come it's "maps"? Perhaps because it's an aggregate of lots of local maps of different regions?

Comment: No idea what they were thinking. But you can use it to generate many maps, directions to specific places, etc. That's why "maps" sounds better to me, the functionality rather than just the aggregate of all the information contained therein. Maps are usually flat, too, and a "map" of the Earth can't be.

Comment: It didn't **used** to be one map of the entire planet... that's relatively recent. Initially they were localized to major cities. Regardless, "Google Map" sounds wrong.

Comment: Yes, there is just one planet and it's all joined together, (zoom out fully and keep scrolling left and it just keeps coming) but there are several different map formats: street map, topological, satellite imagery, perspective, etc. The only other plural in the Google catalog is "Photos", which suggests that Google does in fact know when to use a plural.

Comment: All of the above, plus, it's the name of a product supplied by a tech company.  Which means it's whatever marketing decides sounds good.

Comment: My theory: in the early days of web maps, led by MapQuest, there was no concept that the pieces all fit together into a single map of the world— because they didn't. You had a few maps for a few cities in a few rich countries, and you had to print them out for them to be useful. MapQuest was thus where you got *maps*, not parts of *the map*. Yahoo *Maps* followed and popularized online maps. Google Maps followed in imitation, and its famous AJAX interface was the *first* time anyone could ever feel like they could browse the world 640 pixels at a time— which they still couldn't in actuality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about Google's site naming convention, which might have a historical basis, but is not about learning English.

Comment: Maybe it's off-topic, but as an English learner, I always kind of thought there must be some English way of precieving things which I don't seem to quite understand, so I felt like asking. Thanks anyway for the comments everybody.